# How can I know from which file the table error is coming for?

Tags: magento2, database

I updated some modules and went up this "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_prod.amazon_nding_authorization' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `amazon_nding_authorization`"

I can't seem to find where it wants that table and why. How can I know this? I did a grep searching for "amazon_nding_authorization" the whole files, how can I find this?

Thanks! Best regards,
Rui Silva

Answer (score 1):

The table should be `amazon_pending_authorization` instead of `amazon_nding_authorization`.

I think some spell mistake happen `vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/Model/ResourceModel/PendingAuthorization.php` check this  file.

Here  `const TABLE_NAME = 'amazon_ending_authorization';`  should be  `const TABLE_NAME = 'amazon_pending_authorization';`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! The table exists as amazon_pending_authorization and in the files it's right too. Since it's not in this file, where can it be wrong?

Comment: I've tested change the table name in database and keeps throwing errors, it's missing every pe in all tables that has it, how can we solve this?

Comment: I figured it out, in the extension they were handling the table names removing all occurrences of the prefix, so it was deleting every "pe" no matter where it was. Thanks for your time!